# jquery ui fileupload error with uppercase filename

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, xmlhttprequest, blueimp

I'm facing aweird error with Blueimp JQuery fileupload. All is working ok, when I upload a png/jpg, however, when the files extension is uppercase the $_POST is empty on server side.

The request is the same in both cases:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:hu-HU,hu;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:4721321
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarybCjGtutGsoqkJ58r
Cookie:language=hu; PHPSESSID=m6ag0h5aqpupseat2eb45vh130; csrftoken=EipVk7qvyTxOxuC9TwY8Wrozy8aWOFZ8
Host:localhost:90
Origin:http://localhost:90
Referer:http://localhost:90/belvaros-ingatlan/ugynok-admin/index.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

The respose differs in the content type.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Feb 2015 19:31:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 33
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2
```

I've checked the $_POST and $_REQUEST in the beginning of the ajax_processing php:

```
global $domain, $cmd, $r_ugynok;
$domain="mydomain.hu";
session_start();
//var_dump($_REQUEST);
//var_dump($_POST);
```

I've search google a lot but could not find a cause of it, nor did I find anything in the sources of fileupload. Any suggesstions, why can this happen?

Answer (score 0):

User error:

`post_max_size` was set too small in php.ini